# Problem with require rack/openid in Rails 3 [native require work properly]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I install plugin open_id_authentication and have this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require': no such file to load -- rack/openid (LoadError)
```

when I try to start `rails server`
Actually, rack-openid installed in my system and i can load it from irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rack/openid'
=> true
```

I tried to add hack to Gemfile as I did with ruby-openid, but it did't help:

```
gem "ruby-openid", :require => "openid"
gem "rack-openid", :require => "rack/openid"
```

I also have tried

```
gem "ruby-openid", :require => "rack/openid"
```

but:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-0.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:38:in `require': no such file to load -- rack/openid (LoadError)
```

In rails 2.3.5 app there isn't this problem and I can't understand why it happens in Rails 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this code at the top of the plugin's init.rb

```
if Rails.version < '3'
  config.gem 'rack-openid', :lib => 'rack/openid', :version => '>=0.2.1'
end
```

Bundler doesn't seem to pick up on the gem requirement so you are missing the `rack-openid` gem.

The solution is to add the following to your `Gemfile` in place of `ruby-openid`. (`rack-openid` depends on `ruby-openid` but gems is aware of this and will install it as needed)

```
gem 'rack-openid', '>=0.2.1', :require => 'rack/openid'
```

Don't forget to run `bundle install` after updating your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem since ruby openID can be very erratic, for small reasons.. I have it installed at work, but can't get it right at home! I will give my working recipe:

I have the **Plugins (ONLY)** 
authlogic_openid from: http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_openid
open-id from: http://github.com/senthilnambi/open-id

The **Gems:**
authlogic (2.1.3)
authlogic-oid (1.0.4)
openid (0.0.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rack-openid (1.0.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.7)

At **environment (ONLY)**:
config.gem "authlogic"

GL!

Comment: Yes it works as Fabiano PS says! Please follow this setup. If not you won't be able to run rake open_id_authentication:db:create!! Thanks a ton Fabiano. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem "rack-openid", :require => "rack/openid"
```

Comment: I tried it, but there is the same error as with `gem "rack-openid", :require => "rack-openid"`

Comment: But did you installed rack-openid or ruby-openid? I updated my answer according to `rack-openid`

Comment: Yes, i did: rack-openid, ruby-openid is installed gems.