# no such file to load -- rack/openid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, rubygems, rack, require

I am working on a rails gem which depends on rack/openid. But when I require it and fire up my application I get this error

```
no such file to load -- rack/openid
```

The gem is installed

```
$ gem list | grep openid
rack-openid (1.3.1, 1.2.0)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
```

I've seen this question but it did NOT helped a lot.

[Problem with require rack/openid in Rails 3 [native require work properly]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316729/problem-with-require-rack-openid-in-rails-3-native-require-work-properly)

PS: I can require it from Irb just fine

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't added your Gem to the `Gemfile`, or you haven't added `rack-openid` as a dependency to your gem.

When Rails starts up, it uses [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to set up the load path to match the `Gemfile.lock` file, so even a gem is installed locally you won't be able to require  it if it isn't listed there.

`Gemfile.lock` is created by bundler based on the gems listed in `Gemfile` and their dependencies.

Make sure the gem you're working on specifies `rack-openid` as a dependency in its `.gemspec`, and then add `gem 'my-gem-name'` to your applications `Gemfile` (replace `my-gem-name` with whatever your gem is actually named).